# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[3]{n^3+2n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[3]{n^3+2n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}$$

I tried multiplying with the conjugate of the formula:

$$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$$

So I got:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^3+2n^2+1-n^3+1}{\sqrt[3]{(n^3+2n^2+1)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(n^3+2n^2+1)(n^3-1)} + \sqrt[3]{(n^3-1)^2}}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2n^2+2}{\sqrt[3]{n^6+4n^5+4n^4+2n^3+4n^2+1} + \sqrt[3]{n^6+2n^5-2n^2-1} + \sqrt[3]{n^6-2n^3+1}}$$

And I saw that we can factor $n^2$ in the denominator and if we do the same in the numerator, we'd get that the limit is equal to $2$. The problem is that my textbook claims that this limit is actually $\dfrac{2}{3}$. I don't see why should I have a $3$ in the denominator since the coefficient of $n^2$ would be $1$ if I would carry out the factoring to detail. So, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide all the terms by $n^{2}$ and take the limit. you will see that the limit is $\frac 2 {1+1+1}$

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier with binomial expansion:

$n\left(1+\dfrac2n+\dfrac1{n^3}\right)^{1/3}-n\left(1-\dfrac1{n^3}\right)^{1/3}$

$=n\left[1+\dfrac13\left(\dfrac2n+\dfrac1{n^3}\right)+o\left(\dfrac1{n^2}\right)
-\left(1-\dfrac13\dfrac1{n^3}+o\left(\dfrac1{n^6}\right)\right)\right]$

Comment: Considering expansions at order $1$ would make it still shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is in the form

$$\sqrt[3]{n^6+...}+ \sqrt[3]{n^6+...}+ \sqrt[3]{n^6+...}\sim 3n^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Since
$(n+1)^3
=n^3+3n^2+$lower order terms,
$(n+2/3)^3
=n^3+2n^2+$lower order terms.

Therefore the left cube root
is about $n+2/3$.

Since the right cube root
is just about $n$,
the difference is about $2/3$.